# Opponent controlled Auras and Greater Auramancy

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent has cast an Aura on my creature,
and then I play [Greater Auramancy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Greater%20Auramancy), does the creature get shroud, or do I have to control the Aura?

Similarly, if an opponent has enchanted one of my lands with an Aura, and then I turn that land into a creature, does the land/creature get shroud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will have shroud.

The relevant rule is:

> 303.4b The object or player an Aura is attached to is called enchanted. The Aura is attached to, or “enchants,” that object or player.

There is no mention of controllers. Something with an Aura attached to it is enchanted, regardless of controllers.

And yes, it does work for a land turned into a creature. The technical details (rules section 613 – Interaction of Continuous Effects) are that type-changing effects are applied in layer 4, while ability-adding effects are applied in layer 6, thus the effect making the land into a creature is always applied before Greater Auramancy's effect.

Comment: It's a bit confusing how "enchanted creature" and "enchanted creatures" mean such different things.

Comment: @Acccumulation "enchanted creature" refers to a single creature with an aura attached, "enchanted creatures" refers to all such creatures. An aura enchantment with "enchanted creature" refers to the creature it's attached to, otherwise "enchanted creature" refers to it as a target or an event of the creature (such as "whenever an enchanted creature dies..."). This is usually the case with plural vs. singular nouns in MtG cards

Comment: @Acccumulation I would argue that there isn't that much room for confusion if "enchanted creatures" is not on an Aura. Note that the Auras such as the Magemark cycle from Guildpact use the more wordy "creatures you control that are enchanted" to avoid this confusion.

Comment: @Acccumulation they don't, not in any way that's not normal for plural words. "Enchanted Creatures" being plural refers to all creatures that are enchanted (generally with a you control added) "Enchanted Creature" being singular refers to only a single creature that is enchanted (usually with the implied "by this aura" to specify which)